# UpdatePanel Questions

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have an update panel that lives in a control that lives on a masterpage.  Is it possible to access the updatepanel and cause it to fire in the code-behind of another aspx page that this control is added to at run-time?

There is one case where a button is clicked on page X, and when that button is clicked, I need the update-panel to run.  I have tried this so far with no luck:

**Code-Behind**

```
udp = FindControl("udpWishlist") as UpdatePanel;
if (udp != null){
    udp.Update();
}
```

**Snippet from control of the UpdatePanel I'm trying to use**

```
<!--update wishlist on cartadd-->
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpWishlist" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbwishlist" runat="server" href="/wishlist.aspx"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: why do you have an update panel on the MasterPage.. I am curious since all other pages will inherit from that MasterPage.. and also accessing objects from the MasterPage you may want to look up the following [MSDN Working with MasterPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) || you can google on the following `<%@ MasterType virtualpath=`

Comment: The `UpdatePanel` is inside the user control?

Comment: @DJKRAZE it's an updatedpanel that is inside a user control that is referenced on the masterpage, and it is shown / hidden with CSS. It is a mobile navigation menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can create a public `Method` inside the user control, like this:

```
public void Update()
{
    udpWishlist.Update();
}
```

Inside the page that contains the `UserControl`:

```
YourUserControlType uc = (YourUserControlType)Page.FindControl("YourUserControlID");
uc.Update();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the update panel lives in another .aspx, it's out of scope for FindControl(). You may be able to do something like:

udp = this.Page.Master.FindControl("udpWishlist") as UpdatePanel;